# Linear Applications applied to Information Tecnologies?

Tags: linear-algebra, information-theory

I understand that Linear Applications are a connection between two vector subspaces, that connection must fulfill three conditions:

[image]

I need to know if there is any use of Linear Applications in information technologies. If there are some concepts to start investigating.

Comment: For the record, the first condition is acutally a consequence of any of the other two...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A famous application of Linear Algebra to technology is [Google Page Rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PageRank).

The various concepts it employs are [stochastic matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix), [eigendecompositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix), and numerical methods for computing the largest magnitude eigenvalue of a matrix, such as [power iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration).

Comment: Ty so much! I'll check that concepts.

Comment: I would just learn linear algebra instead. Applications can come later.

Comment: While I was investigating, I could not find any connection between what I know as Linear Applications and Google Page Rank. Can you indicate some specific part about what you consider Linear applications in Google PageRanks?

Comment: What you call a "linear application" is what most people call a *linear function*. A *matrix* is a linear function between finite dimensional vector spaces. Therefore, anything involving matrices is a viable application.